# How to find counts of items belonging to weekends and weekdays

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in sql server. I have to create a report listing weekday and weekend order counts placed by each person. So far I have the following query and it produces the desired result.

```
select 
(select sum(case when DATEPART(DW, o.Order_DateTime) not between 2 and 6  
            then 1 else 0
       end)  
 from Order_Data o 
 where o.email_address = @email) as WeekEndOrders,
 (select sum(case when DATEPART(DW, o.Order_DateTime) between 2 and 6  
            then 1 else 0
       end)  
 from Order_Data o 
 where o.email_address = @email) as WeekDayOrders
```

I want to have the first subquery to check whether DW is 1 or 7, which will correspond to weekends - Sunday and Saturday. Since I didn't know how to do it I am using, "not between 2 and 6". Also any idea to write this query in a better way. For example, combining these two repeating subqueries into a single one, still producing the two - WeekEndOrders and WeekDayOrders - counts. Since it's going to be part of a huge query, having it as a subquery is fine.

Comment: You could write 1 or 7 as `IN (1, 7)`. Also, you could rewrite the entire query in one select instead of two subqueries unless I'm missing something. The where clause and the table you're selecting from is the same, so I can't see a reason not to just do something like: `select weekendorders = sum(case when datepart(..) in (1, 7) then 1 else 0 end), weekdayorders = sum(...) from order_data where email_address = @email;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way.

```
 select 
   sum(iif(DATEPART(DW, o.Order_DateTime) in (1, 7), 1, 0)  WeekEndOrders,
   sum(iif(DATEPART(DW, o.Order_DateTime) not in (1, 7), 1, 0)  WeekDayOrders
 from Order_Data o 
 where o.email_address = @email
```

PS: `IIF (condition, true_part, false_part)` does same thing  with `case when <condition> then <true_part> else <false_part> end`